# Regex to add style attribute to a specific <table> tag

Tags: regex

** >> Please see Update near the bottom**

I am having to deal with a large amount of imported HTML code that is poorly formatted.

I have around 200 similar (but not identical) instances of the code, and each instance includes a specific set of `<img>` tags. In some instances, the `<img>` tags run from one to the next, with no line breaks in between. In other instances there are line breaks in the code, and these result in `<br>` tags being inserted into the final code sent to the browser.

This will make more sense once I illustrate what I mean:

Example #1: There are no breaks between the `<img>` tags...

```
<table align="center" border="0px"> <tbody><tr> <td> <img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/CustomerSatisfaction.png" alt="100% Customer Satisfaction" height="60" align="middle" width="140"> <img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/PaypalVerified.png" alt="Paypal Verified" height="60" align="middle" width="140"> <img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/FastDelivery.png" alt="Fast Delivery" height="60" align="middle" width="140"> <img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/Recycled.png" alt="100% Recyled Pre-owned Products" height="60" align="middle" width="140"> <img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/TopSellerRated.png" alt="Top Seller Rated" height="60" align="middle" width="140"> <img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/PhoneSupport.png" alt="Phone Support" height="60" align="middle" width="140"> </td> </tr> </tbody></table>
```

Example #2: There are breaks between the `<img>` tags...

```
<table align="center" border="0px">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/CustomerSatisfaction.png" alt="100% Customer Satisfaction" align="middle" height="60" width="140"> 
<img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/PaypalVerified.png" alt="Paypal Verified" align="middle" height="60" width="140"> 
<img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/FastDelivery.png" alt="Fast Delivery" align="middle" height="60" width="140"> 
<img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/Recycled.png" alt="100% Recyled Pre-owned Products" align="middle" height="60" width="140"> 
<img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/TopSellerRated.png" alt="Top Seller Rated" align="middle" height="60" width="140"> 
<img src="http://simplicitywebsitedesign.com/iOutlet/images/buttons/PhoneSupport.png" alt="Phone Support" align="middle" height="60" width="140">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

As mentioned, for reasons unknown to me, the Wordpress site on which this code is utilised throws in `<br>` tags when code example #2 is parsed through to the browser.

That results in the images displaying as follows (on Firefox):

[image: The way example #2 displays]

Code sample #1 displays link this:

[image: The way exmple #1 displays]

I am thinking the best way to resolve this is do to a search/replace via MySQL on the DB, using a regular expression that will identify instances of code example #2 and make it like code example #1. In other words, the line breaks will be removed from between the relevant `<img>` tags.

Two questions:

1) Is that in fact the best way to go about this, or is there a potentially better way?

2) If that is a valid and suitable way to do it, would you suggest a suitable regular expression.

(With question 2, I am not sure what to suggest as the correct regex engine. This regex will be parsed within MySQL, using the Mac app Sequel Pro.app (http://www.sequelpro.com/).

### My take on the possible Regex logic

My guess is that we need to:

1) Find instance of `<table...> ... </table>`

2) Find instances of `</img>` (soft line break) `<img ...>` within code identified by #1 above

3) Remove (soft line break)

There is one other `<table> ... </table>` set within the code that will be searched. There is only one `<img>` within that instance. There are exactly 6 `<img>` instances within the `<table> ... </table>`

### Update, taking comments into account

It has been suggested that I use the `flex` CSS `display` attribute, and apply it to the table row. I've done that, and it works well. I am a little concerned about compatibility on older browsers, as I gather it's a relatively recent CSS addition.

I do, however, still need to do a search/replace to locate the correct `<table>` in the HTML.

In most of the HTML instances, there are two instances of `<table> ... </table>`. So I suspect the regex would need to do a negative forward check for something like `/stars/` which exists in a URL that's in the `<table>` instance I **don't** want modified. Then it would be a matter of replacing `<table>` with `<table id="green-icons">`

Thanks.

Jonathan

P.S. I am aware there is a [LOT of contention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1092677) around whether or not regex is a valid way to make changes to HTML. As this is a relatively fixed and known set of HTML, I suspect it'll be okay. But I am also open to other suggestions.

Comment: You Don't need RegEx, `float: left` is all you need.

Comment: @Tushar, so I just apply that style attribute to each `<img>` or somewhere else?

Comment: or use flexbox, its much better :) on the parent element (in this case td, but you should make a specific identifier for that. Maybe add an extra class to the table and then use: `table.row td { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }`

Comment: @Tushar, If I add `float: left` to each image (which I now recall is something I tried previously, when working on this last week) the images get horizontally skewed, like this:  https://snag.gy/6pEUAi.jpg

Comment: @noreabu: brilliant. That did it nicely. So what I need now is the regex to locate and modify the table with the new class.

Comment: I also tried added `text-align: center;` to css for this new class, but it has no effect. How would I go about centering the row of images?

Comment: use for example `justify-content: space-between;` check out http://caniuse.com for browser compatibility

Comment: I tried adding `justigy-content: space-between;` to the class, but doesn't seem to have made any difference. Any other suggestions? What I have got so far is, `table.green-buttons td {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; /* Safari 6.1+ */
justify-content: space-between;
}`  I tried adding in `  align-items: center;` and also `  text-align: center;` all to no avail